# How can I have "list style position outside" and floating elements in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-float

The following markup is not something I can change as it's based on user content. The problem is that in IE9 the bullets in a `ul` that are next to a floated `img` appear on the wrong side of the image. This is only a problem in IE9. The way the `ul` wraps the image is desired behavior and something I'd like to keep but that makes this problem really hard to solve.
Any ideas on how to solve this without changing the markup and in a way that looks good cross-browser?

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/fdHN6/

**EDIT :** I should have mention this, `list-style-position: inside` causes the last bullet point which has more than one line of text to align incorrectly which is why that alone is not really a good solution.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:500px;">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/303" alt="smelly cat" />
            <ul style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine!</li>
                <li>Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine! Mine</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>

body{
    margin-left:35px;
}

img {
    margin:20px;
    float:left;
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Comment: sorry im using linux (no ie9) do you mean that the ul is on the left side of the image or that the bullet points are over the image but the text on the right side of it.

becuase if you mean that the bullet points are on the image you just need to set the correct margin and padding of the li and ul (its on every browser diffrent)

Comment: @micha the bullet points appear on the left side of the image and the text on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

should solve your issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/fdHN6/1/

UPDATE: Using pseudo-elements you can achieve a similar effect, while preserving the text-indent:

http://jsfiddle.net/fdHN6/3/

Comment: Sorry probably should have mentioned this but with list-style-position: inside; the text of the last bullet point gets misaligned which is why it has more text than the other bullets as a way to illustrate this.

Comment: Not a great solution, but here goes: [http://jsfiddle.net/fdHN6/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/fdHN6/3/)

Comment: It doesn't work in Compatibility View so I'll have to use a conditional but that's fine. Thanks man.

Comment: I'm not too happy with having to position the text with an exact value for padding, but it's all I could come up with for now. I'll let you know if I come across a better solution; not sure when I'd run into this same problem though. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to find a fix.

I had an image floated on the left and a UL to its right side. I wanted the list position to be outside so the text that spans multiple lines aligns nicely on the left. However in IE9 the bullets ran to the left, over the image, rather than floating to the right of the image.

So I use list-style-postion:inside; for the UL and I also added a negative text-indent for it, -12px worked perfect for me, you'll need to vary that until it fits your needs.

Comment: If you use text-indent, only the first line of the list item will be indented. Because of this your solution is not suitible for multiline-list-elements. See [CSS-Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-indent)

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue.
I used

```
ul {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style-position: inside;
 text-indent: 1em;
 margin-left: 0;
}

li {
 padding-left: 1em;
}
```

overflow hidden create a new formatting context  and force the box to "clear" the float. This way the bullet "respect" the floated image.

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/

Seems to work alright.

Answer (score 1):

Make the ul display as a table.

`ul{display:table;}`